# Strange limit with exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Using  [this wolfram alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%282%5Ex-7%29%5E%281%2F%283-x%29%29), I found that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 3} (2^x - 7)^{1/(3-x)} = \frac{1}{256}.
\end{equation}

How can i come up with that limit (1/256) ? How to convert this expression ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). A link to wolfram alpha shows little effort in formatting of your question.

Comment: This [handout](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2077549-7075099-600126/seq2.pdf) of mine from the 1990s may be useful. You can also try googling the phrase "exponential indeterminate forms".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $L=\lim_{x \to 3} (2^x-7)^{\frac{1}{3-x}} = \lim_{t \to 0} (2^{t+3}-7)^{-\frac{1}{t}}$.

Taking logarithms, we have

$$\log L = \lim_{t \to 0} -\frac{\log(8\cdot2^t - 7)}{t} = - \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log(1+8(2^t-1))}{t} = - \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{8(2^t-1)}{t}$$

where I used in the last step that $u \sim \log(1+u)$. Finally, using L'Hopital

$$\log L =  -8\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2^t-1}{t} = -8 \log 2$$
hence $L= e^{-8 \log 2} = \frac{1}{2^8}$.

Comment: One can avoid l'Hôpital by recalling that $\log2^t=t\log2$, so $2^t=e^(t\log2)$; substituting $u=t\log2$ we have $\lim_{t\to0}(2^t-1)/t=\lim_{u\to0}\log2(e^u-1)/u$ and this limit is a basic one.

Answer (score 0):

Logs:

Taking the log of the experssion we have

$$\frac{1}{3-x}\log (2^x - 7) = \frac{1}{3-x}\log (1+(2^x - 8)) \approx \frac{(2^x - 8)}{3-x}$$
Now use l'Hopital's rule to get this limit which turns out to be $-8 \log 2$.

Therefore your original limit has a value of $2^{-8}$ as Wolfram says.